# Open a new Firefox Window with a Profile already open | Bash, Linux

Tags: linux, bash, firefox, macros

I want to create a Macro so that I can open frequently used websites.
I have a studying macro and a personal macro. The code looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

firefox -P "Profile A" -no-remote -new-tab -url "link" -new-tab -url "link" -new-tab -url "link" &
```

However, if I want to run this script with a Profile thats already open I get the following error

> Firefox is already running, but is not responding. To use Firefox, you
> must first close the existing Firefox process, restart your device, or
> use a different profile.

I want to be able to open tabs with an already opened profile

What should I do?

PS: Running Ubuntu (POP OS)

Comment: See https://www.how2shout.com/linux/open-firefox-with-url-command-line-linux/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the option `-no-remote` from my KDE desktop shortcuts (I use different profiles), scripts and keystroke associations and that fixed the problem.

The other options you are using to invoke firefox should work as expected.